# Custom slider in iOS

Tags: ios, ipad

Hi I am developing a iPad Application and I need to develop a custom slider.Please suggest me if anyone has idea about it.[image]

Comment: Why do you think you need a custom slider? What needs to be custom about it?

Comment: so how can I create it?

Comment: Use a `UISlider` with some custom images. See the docs for `UISlider`.

Answer (score 9):

Ray Wenderlich's site has a great tutorial on user interface customizations, including `UISlider` customization:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6

While titled as "in iOS 6", most of this tutorial is applicable starting in iOS 5.